# Swiper - slideable menu full width

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

I would like to use [swiper slide menu](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/32-slideable-menu.html) in my project built with bootstrap 4. 
I have a navigation that looks like this, where the menu button is placed on the right side on small screens:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded">

      <div class="menu-button navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right">
         <div class="bar"></div>
         <div class="bar"></div>
         <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="logo-link">
        <img src="{{ asset('/img/logo-small-new.png') }}" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between" id="navbar5">
          <form action="/search" method="get" class="my-auto d-inline mx-auto col-md-8" role="search">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                  <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                    <i class="ion-ios-search-strong"></i>
                  </button>
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="search-input" name="q" class="form-control aa-input-search" placeholder="Search for players and videos ..."  value="{{ Request::get('q') }}" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
          </form>
          <ul class="navbar-nav my-auto">
              @if (Auth::check())
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      <i class="ion-ios-gear-outline"></i>
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/home') }}">Admin dashboard</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                          onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                          Log out
                      </a>
                      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </li>
              @else
              <li>
                <a href="{{ url('/login') }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Sign in</a>
              </li>
              @endif
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Now it works like in the demo shown [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/32-slideable-menu.html), but I would like the menu to take the full width, and the menu button to be visible in the right corner when the menu is open. If I comment out some of the css properties for the menu:

```
.menu {
    min-width: 100px;
    /* width: 70%; */
    /* max-width: 320px; */
    background-color: #2C8DFB;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Then the menu is full width, but the menu button is not visible, I have tried with giving the big z-index to it, but that didn't help. What do I need to do to have it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat*: I made these changes to the code in the demo you linked. I didn't play with the html you've pasted here.

You were on the right track. Remove out the `width` and `max-width` as you did already.

```
.menu {
    min-width: 100px;   
    background-color: #2C8DFB;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Then add the following `css` to move the button to the top right when you expand the menu:

```
.menu-button.cross{
    left: -80px;
}
```

If you want a fullwidth menu and the button on the top right to **only** apply on small screens you'll need to use a media query. Modify the below code as necessary.

```
/*smaller screen css*/
.menu {
    min-width: 100px;   
    background-color: #2C8DFB;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu-button.cross{
    left: -80px;
}
media (min-width: 768px) {
    /*larger screen css*/
    .menu {
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 320px;
    }
    .menu-button.cross{
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, is there a way to set the menu height to 100% of the viewport, because now it is the height of the content. I have tried with setting the menu height to 100vh, and overflow-y: hidden, but that didn't work.

Comment: @Leff Try this css for the menu element: `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;` and then `position: relative` for the div containing the menu. Get rid of setting the menu height manually.

Comment: If I do that, then the menu covers the content.

Comment: @Leff You should only apply that css to the active menu. When you click the menu button the class names of the html element change. In the demo for example it changes to `swiper-slide-active`. Apply the css to this only. You'll need to give the menu it's own class too, to differentiate it from the content slide. So a selector like `.swiper-slide-active.my-menu{ /*css here*/}`. If I'm misunderstanding we'll need a demo of your actual use case. It's hard to see what you mean. This should also probably be a separate SO question.

Comment: You are right, I will try with your suggestion and give you the bounty for this question, thank you very much for your help!